# How to set margin between item on row android table layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

How to set margin between item on row android table layout

I don't know how to set margin between item on row

[image]

my code here I think some thing wrong I don't know how to set margin between item on 1st row and 2nd row

```
   <TableRow

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:background="@drawable/editshape2"
             />

        <ImageView

            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:background="@drawable/editshape2"
            />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/editshape2"
             />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:background="@drawable/editshape2"
             />

    </TableRow>
```

Comment: did you try margin-left ? atrribute

Comment: User margin or margin-left for that..i already try ..<ImageView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:padding="2dp"  android:margin="5dp"                                                                                        
            android:background="@drawable/editshape2"
             />

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this attributes on imageView column="0"

```
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
```

Try to add this attributes on imageView column="1"

```
android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your `TableLayout`:

```
android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
android:showDividers="middle"
```

Answer (score 1):

> android:layout_marginLeft="50dp" ,this can be used in second element of a row .

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:background="@drawable/editshape2"
         />

    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:background="@drawable/editshape2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        />

</TableRow>

<TableRow

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/editshape2"
         />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:background="@drawable/editshape2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
         />

</TableRow>
```